# Parameter 0 of method websocketRoutingFilter in org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayAutoConfiguration required a bean of type

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am developing code by taking reference from : https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2018/04/26/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-spring-boot-2-0-eureka-and-spring-cloud/. In this example, I'm using Spring Boot V `2.1.1.RELEASE` and spring-cloud-dependencies as `Finchley.RELEASE`.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I am getting below error while starting the `gateway-service`:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-21 19:59:47 ERROR [gateway-service,,,] 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method websocketRoutingFilter in org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.WebSocketClient' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'reactorNettyWebSocketClient' in 'GatewayAutoConfiguration.NettyConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.WebSocketClient' in your configuration.
```

[image]

And also getting below error while starting `proxy-service`. How can I resolve this?

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-21 20:02:19 ERROR [proxy-service,,,] 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'proxyRequestHelper', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration$NoActuatorConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration$EndpointConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

**GatewayApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8088
```

**ProxyApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableSwagger2
public class ProxyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProxyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ProxyApi.java

```
@Configuration
public class ProxyApi {

    @Autowired
    ZuulProperties properties;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider() {
        return () -> {
            List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
            properties.getRoutes().values().stream()
                    .forEach(route -> resources.add(createResource(route.getServiceId(), route.getId(), "2.0")));
            return resources;
        };
    }

    private SwaggerResource createResource(String name, String location, String version) {
        SwaggerResource swaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
        swaggerResource.setName(name);
        swaggerResource.setLocation("/" + location + "/v2/api-docs");
        swaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion(version);
        return swaggerResource;
    }
}
```

I've seen https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/319, but I still want to use the Spring Boot V`2.1.1.RELEASE`.

Comment: Gateway is not compatible with tomcat, jetty or undertow. And Finchley is not compatible with boot 2.1.x

Comment: Could you please suggest which latest version of Boot and Spring Cloud are compatible with each other ? Do you've reference shown in the spring docs?

Comment: See "Release Trains" here https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: You should be using Greenwich with Spring Boot 2.1

Comment: @Matt Busche could you please elaborate?

Comment: Greenwich is  the spring cloud version you should be using with spring boot 2.1 https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/21/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc2-is-now-available